# javascript, for loop defines a dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript

Folks,
  Not sure if eval() or window() is the answer, but I am trying to loop through an array, and create variables for each item in that array dynamically.

My myArray looks like:

```
['foo','bar','baz']
```

code:

```
for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   var myVar = eval(myArray[i])
};

console.log(foo)
console.log(bar)
console.log(baz)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but why would you do that instead of keeping the array as an associated array, say in an object?  Your eval would need to look something *like* this `eval('var ' + myArray[i]);`

Comment: and what should `foo`,`bar` and `baz` hold ?

Comment: Some clarification on _why_ you need to do something like this would be useful. Generally, anything you can do with `eval` is better done a different way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do it by creating parameters in an object maybe?

```
var myObject = {};
for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    myObject[ myArray[i] ];
}
```

If you don't set them to anything, you'll just have an object with some parameters that are undefined.  I'd have to write this myself to be sure though.

Comment: You still need to assign a value to the property, but your idea is correct.

Comment: +1 @thgaskell. It should be `myObject[myArray[i]] = true` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create different "variable names" but you can create different object properties. There are *many* ways to do whatever it is you're actually trying to accomplish. In your case I would just do

```
for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   console.log(eval(myArray[i]));
};
```

More generally you can create object properties dynamically, which is the type of flexibility you're thinking of.

```
var result = {};
for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result[myArray[i]] = eval(myArray[i]);  
};
```

I'm being a little handwavey since I don't actually understand language theory, but in pure Javascript (including Node) references (i.e. variable names) are happening at a higher level than at runtime. More like at the call stack; you certainly can't manufacture them in your code like you produce objects or arrays. Browsers do actually let you do this anyway though it's *terrible* practice, via

```
window['myVarName'] = 'namingCollisionsAreFun';
```

(per comment)

Comment: In javascript, you can create variable names dynamically, it's just in this case a bad idea. For instance, in a browser `window['myVarName'] = 'namingCollisionsAreFun'; console.log(myVarName);`

Comment: Note that neither of the for loops shown here will work: they'll both give a `ReferenceError: baz is not defined` error on the first iteration when trying to do `eval(myArray[i])` (which would be `eval('baz')`). They should just access `myArray[i]` directly without `eval()`.